# what is React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef for react typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

For using React with typescript, what is `React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef` used for. Is there any documentation for this property?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The ComponentPropsWithoutRef type can be used to grab all the native attributes of an HTML element as the props type of your component.

You can simply create a type that has all the native button attributes as props like this:

```
type ButtonProps = React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"button">
const Button = ({ children, onClick, type }: ButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} type={type}>
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

Here a [link](https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-with-typescript-cheatsheet-9dd891dc5bfe) that talks about usage of ComponentPropsWithoutRef in typescript more. Refer "How to type (extend) HTML elements" and "ComponentPropsWithoutRef vs [Element]HTMLAttributes" sections

Comment: TLDR: `React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"button">` is shorter than `React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>`

Comment: Indeed, 40 is less than 45. (◠‿◠)